# Which programmers work with the Atmel Raven boards?

Tags: avr, avrdude

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242817/how-do-i-program-an-avr-raven-with-linux-or-a-mac/2809748#2809748) answers the question of if it possible to program an Atmel AVR Raven board with avrdude or not.  Yes, it is possible.

My question is which programmers will work with the Atmel Raven + avrdude?  I'm trying to avoid buying the $300+ AVR JTAGICE mkII.  There are clones available for $50 (for example the [AVR-ISP500](http://www.olimex.com/dev/avr-isp500.html) from Olimex).

Can anyone confirm having used a clone programmer with avrdude to program the Atmel Raven boards? Which programmer(s)?

Comment: Do you want the debugging functionality of the JTAGICE?  *That's* the source of your price difference, not the Atmel vs. clone question.  Also, the Olimex part you linked to is a clone of the programmer parts of the STK500, not the ICE.

Comment: No I don't want the debugging functionality of JTAGICE. But if I purchase the Raven evaluation set I just want to know that I will be able to compile and load the binaries onto the modules (preferably using Linux).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of what I have found:

The Raven boards as well as the Raven stick both contain 10-pin, 50-mil JTAG interfaces.  The pins must be soldered on by the user but are also included in the evaluation kit.  A 50-mil to 100-mil adapter allows connecting the JTAG interfaces to programmers.

The Raven boards but not the Raven stick include 6-pin, 50-mil ISP interfaces.  The pins for these must be soldered on as well but no 6-pin units are shipped with the evaluation set.  However, as they are only header pins, the 10-pin units that ship with the evaluation set can be broken off to create 6-pin units. (See [link](http://www.outsidetrains.com/raven/), search for “ISP connectors”).

The ISP interfaces on the Raven boards are faulty; VCC and GND are not connected for the 1284p MCU.  Atmel has suggested a workaround by jumping those pins to the VCC and GND pins for the 3290p ISP header. (See [link](http://code.rancidbacon.com/LearningAboutAtmelRZRAVEN), search for “7 July 2008”).

The Raven stick does not contain an ISP interface at all, however, clever hacking and soldering can change that.  See [here](http://www.outsidetrains.com/raven/) (search for “USB stick”) and [here](http://ossmann.blogspot.com/2010/01/killerbee-on-budget.html) for more information.

To summarize: it is possible to use a cheap ISP programmer with the Raven boards however it will require some extra soldering on the Raven boards in addition to adding the pins and it will also require quite a hack to the Raven stick.  Nevertheless it is possible and has been done before.

Which leaves with the recommended JTAG interface to program the Raven boards and stick.  JTAG programmers can be expensive.  The Atmel JTAGICE mkII programmer and debugger goes for around $300.  Clones are cheaper, for example the Olimex AVRISP-500, and while the clones don’t allow debugging more importantly they do not support all AVR chips.  The AVR Dragon goes for around $60 and supports JTAG albeit with its debugging capabilities artificially limited to the first 32kb of an application so as not to cannibalize sales of the higher end JTAG device. Nevertheless, I find the Dragon to be the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

Any programmer/debugger that supports the AVR controllers on the Raven boards should be suitable, I'd use an AVR Dragon ($50) instead of the specified JTAG ICE Mk II. Clones like that one available from Olimex only support programming, not debugging.

The JTAG ICE Mk II might still be available for half-price from Arrow.

Comment: Arrow appears to be out of stock at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [TuxGraphics AVRUSB500](http://shop.tuxgraphics.org/electronic/index-avr-programmer.html) to program my Raven-USB (after [wiring on the ISP header](http://ossmann.blogspot.com/2010/01/killerbee-on-budget.html))

Comment: I have the same TuxGraphics programmer.

Comment: Is there a way to use the TuxGraphic programmer (6 pins) without changing the Raven board? Is there a pin adapter that will work? How about the other Raven boards apart from JackDaw?

Comment: I only have the USB board, for that - there's no other way, the ISP pins aren't brought out